# Turn back systemctl service after remove

Tags: debian, sshd, systemctl

Incidental I call

`systemctl disable sshd`

I have no Idea it would delete node, but it is.
I only want to prevent it from auto starting while boot.

How to turn back sshd to be controlled from systemctl (re-install wasn't helpful) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`systemctl disable sshd` removes symbolic links which prevents the service from starting on boot, it's not deleting anything else. If you want to enable it back, do `sudo systemctl enable ssh` (note that it's `ssh` not `sshd` in Debian/Ubuntu, after you enable it it will create a 2nd symlink named `sshd`).